# Given a mass and position as a function of time, find work

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work

> A single force acts on a $7.0 kg$ particle-like object in such a way that the position of the object as a function of time is given by $x = 3.0t − 4.0t^2 + 1.0t^3$, with $x$ in meters and $t$ in seconds. Find the work done on the object by the force from $t = 0s$ to $t = 7.0 s$.

My thinking:
$dW = Fdr$ where $F = force$, $dr =$ change in position
$F = ma$ where $m =$ mass, $a =$ accelleration
$a =$ second derivative of position with respect to time $= 6t-8$
$dW=m(6t-8)(3.0t − 4.0t^2 + 1.0t^3)dt$
integrate from $0$ to $7$ seconds and I'm off by a couple orders of magnitude. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the force F is ma, where $a = (6t-8)$.  The work is the integral of $Fdx$, with $dx = (3-8t+3t^2)dt$.  So, $$dW=m(6t-8)(3-8t+3t^2)dt=\frac{m}{2}d[(3-8t+3t^2)^2]$$

Comment: Doing this for my new problem where x is the same, m = 2g and t = 0 to 5s gives me 1435 J but the expected answer is 1440 J.

Comment: I get 1444Jpules

Comment: 1444 is for t = 5, at t=0 it's 9, so 1444-9 = 1435. It turns out the answer is 1440 because of significant figures.

Answer (score 0):

You're integrating *Force* times *Position* over *Time* (the units don 't work). Try integrating *Force* times *Velocity* (*Power*) over *Time*, since *Power* times *Time* is *Energy*.

Note that:

$$ W = \int{F\cdot dx} \ne \int{ma(t)x(t)dt} = m\int{(6t-8)(t^3-4t^2+3t)dt} $$

because:

$$ dx = \frac{dx}{dt}dt = v(t)dt = (3t^2 - 8t + 3)dt $$.

So:

$$ W = m\int{(6t-8)(3t^2-8t+3)dt} = m[4.5t^4-24t^3+41t^2-24t]^{t=7}_{t=0}$$

Turns out, this is the same as the change in kinetic energy:

$$ \Delta T \equiv \frac 1 2 m v(t)^2|^{t=7}_{t=0}$$

Comment: I had thought this, (Since F*v*a gives kg m^2/s^3 and integrating results in kg m^2/s^s or J) but the answer that I was supposed to arrive at was closer to 1kJ. I'm working on a practice problem on a website. The practice problem has changed so I don't have access to the old "correct" answer. The function is the same, but now it's a 2kg particle, and the time is 0-5 sec. The answer I arrived at is 6435 J, the answer I was supposed to get is 1440 J.

Comment: What really confuses me is that there is a shortcut that says I can subtract the square of the initial velocity from the square of the final velocity and multiply that by half the mass. That gets me close enough to the expected answer that it will accept it, but not the expected answer. I'm confused because that shortcut is found by integrating ma dx.

Comment: After reading Chester's answer and working out the math for myself I understand the shortcut, but not why my answer is still not right.

Comment: @Anazopyreo: not sure why this was down voted, since it's right: you asked what you did wrong--and you what did wrong was integrate $\int{ma(t)x(t)dt}$, which doesn't even have the units of energy. I said integrate $\int{ma(t)v(t)dt}$, which _has_ the correct units, _is_ the correct answer, and is _equal_ to $\frac{1}{2}m v(t)^2$.

Comment: I noticed that my original question and some answers were down-voted right from the start.

Comment: @Anazopyreo There is nothing wrong with the root question; moreover, you posed it correctly- showing the effort that you had made, and explicitly pointing out where you became unsure of the result---so there's really no reason to down vote.

Comment: Thanks, I was upset by the implication. I just spoke to my prof and hammered out exactly how to do the problem and round to account fr significant figures, which always throws me off.

Answer (score 0):

The work done is equal to the change in Kinetic energy.

$v(0)=3m/s$

$v(7)=94m/s$

That gives: $\text{Work} = \text{KE}_7 - \text{KE}_0 =31kJ$

Comment: We haven't covered energy yet, but 31 KJ is about what I get when I try integrating acceleration and velocity with respect to time as in my comment to the other answer. But that apparently is not correct.